# Parsing out all Special Characters

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop

I'll preface my question by saying I know using strictly regex for this is a lot easier/cleaner of a solution and I plan on refactoring my code to do just that.

That said, I wanted to see if my brute force way could actually work.

Basically, this is a simple letter substitution cipher that replaces a letter with the letter 13 letters after it in the alphabet.

If the letter is a special character, it keeps that special character.

I have my function returning the correct letters and have some regex code in there to check for special characters but it keeps saying it is finding 13 occurrences of a special character and I can't seem to figure out why. Any thoughts?

```js
function rot13(message) {
  let alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  let capAlpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  let special = /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?\s]/g;
  let arrAlpha = alpha.split("")
  let messageSplit = message.split("")
  let sum = 0
  let newSum = 0
  let answer = []

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < alpha.length; j++) {
      if (message[i] === alpha[j]) {
        if (j <= 12) {
          answer.push(alpha[j + 13])
        } else {
          sum = 25 - j
          newSum = 12 - sum
          answer.push(alpha[newSum]);
          sum = 0
        }
      } else if (message[i] === capAlpha[j]) {
        if (j <= 12) {
          answer.push(capAlpha[j + 13])
        } else {
          sum = 25 - j
          newSum = 12 - sum
          answer.push(capAlpha[newSum]);
          sum = 0
        }
      } else if (special.test(message[i])) {
        console.log("hello");
        answer.push(message[i])
      }
    }
  }
  return (answer.join(""));
}

console.log(rot13("Hello"));
console.log("---------------");
rot13("Hello World!");
```

Comment: What `message` value causes this issue? If I just call `rot13('a')` then does the issue occur?

Comment: You are iterating over the entire alphabet for every character in the message string, so when you get to the `!` in `Hello World!` your loop hits the `special.test` conditional every time and logs.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It would be something like, rot13("Test@")

Comment: I see. Looks like someone provided an answer so I'll just suggest the following change: `let special = /[^a-z]/gi;`. It case-insensitively matches any char which is not a through z; the literal opposite of `alpha` and `capAlpha`

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in this snippet:

```
else if (special.test(message[i])) {
        console.log("hello");
        answer.push(message[i])
      }
```

Because you're looping over the length of alpha, it's executing that check 13 times, and thus pushing the space into answer 13 times. If you add `break;` after the push, it'll exit the j loop and proceed to the next iteration of the i loop.